# Directive changes CSS when element is active

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm *very* new to Angular so I'm sure this isn't correct but I have a set of `<li>` elements which further contain links (individually, they're just navigation buttons for my page). What I'd like is to keep the specific button, say, "Home" highlighted a certain color while the user is on that page. So my html roughly looks like this...

```
    <li class="active menuBar">
      <a ui-sref="aap.configure.views" change-css="aap.isActive()">
        <div class="row text-center">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 2.5em;"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <span class="glyphicon-class">Home</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
```

I literally just wrote my first custom Directive yesterday so here's my second attempt at one...

```
app.directive( 'changeCss', [ '$location',
    function ( ) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                active: '&'
            },
            link: function( $scope, element, attrs ){
                if( $scope.active ){
                    element.addClass( 'actives');
                }
                else {
                    element.addClass( 'inActives' );
                }
            }

        };
    }
] );
```

And my `isActive()` function looks like...

```
    var active = false;
    $scope.aap.isActive = function( ){
        if ( active ){
            active = false;
            return true;
        } else {
            active = true;
            return false;
        };
    };
```

Now, when I load up the page all the navigation buttons (Home, Save, etc.) are the color I'd like them to be. Clicking on a button, say, "Home" highlights that button in the color I'd like it to be. But, when I interact with that Home page at all, click an accordion element for instance, the color goes back to the "inactive" color. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure for this. but I hope this might help you. If you want to set the active/inactive of your navigation bar base on your page.

I use ng-class for setting active of the navigation bar (see here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) by passing the uri to the function getClass().

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li ng-class="{'active': getClass('/dashboard')}" >
            <a href="/">
                Dashboard
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{'active': getClass('/session')}">
            <a ng-href="/session">
                Sessions
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

at my Controller I check the location path and sends boolean for activating/deactivating the ng-class

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$location','$scope', function ($location, $scope) {

        $scope.getClass = function(path) {            
            if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) == path) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
        }           

    }]);
```